# Can Control Panel Settings page become very slow with some plugins?

Tags: plugins, performance

Despite my best intentions to build sites with minimal use of plugins (in any CMS) I have resorted to a dozen or so on one Craft site with about 25 sections and 1000 entries, to help with both CP and front-end things. Since the v2.5 upgrade (I think) I noticed that the Settings page had become impossibly slow to load (about 30 seconds, and this often within the Settings area too) which stretches my tolerance when I am working. I disabled all loaded plugins and suddenly everything was good again. I then added plugins one by one and tested the Settings page loading time. It eventually came down to two (Cache Warmer and Sitemap) that slowed loading time, and the effect seemed to be cumulative (i.e. one plugin was only half as slow). Is it a reasonable assumption that some plugins may affect Settings page loading time, and has anyone else noticed this? What can I do about it?

I guess someone will mention the L-word (logs) but I always have a hard time understanding which log files to look at and what to look for.

Comment: I'm not sure the exact logic behind it, but each plugin's Settings page will be quietly accessed on the main Settings page. So there may be something about their particular Settings pages which is causing an unusually heavy load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it a reasonable assumption that some plugins may affect Settings page loading time

It's very reasonable.  A plugin can do all sorts of things that might slow down CP rendering and it's reasonable to assume that all plugins don't test with databases that have 25 sections and thousands of entries.

The log files you want to look at are in `craft/storage/runtime/logs`. `craft.log` is the most recent and `craft.log.1`, `.2`, etc. being older. Do it with [devMode](http://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#devMode) enabled and you want to be looking at the timestamps for each entry to see where all of the time is being eaten up.

Alternatively (or in addition to), you can create a [Github](https://github.com/sjelfull/Craft-CacheWarmer/issues) issue for CacheWarmer and let them know what you're seeing.

Sitemap is commercial, so you can go through the [developer's](https://www.putyourlightson.net/about) usual support channels.